# cordova plugman - adding the first platform specific plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugman

*my system dependencies:*

- cordova: @7.1.0
- plugman: @2.0.0

I want to use `plugman` to install plugins only to specific platform (e.g. android)

I have [read the docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html) and the workflow and usage is not so clear.
After creating fresh new cordova project, running successfully the following commands:

```
cordova create hello-world
cordova platform add android
```

I wanted to install my first platform specific plugin using this command:

```
plugman install --platform android --project ./ --plugin cordova-plugin-battery-status
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined
    at C:\Users\liranCo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\fetch.js:168:18
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\liranCo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\liranCo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\liranCo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\liranCo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:509:49
    at flush (C:\Users\liranCo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:686:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
```

What is the correct worklow for adding the first platform specific plugin?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this keeps happpening on plugman@2.0.

Install plugman@1.5.1

`npm remove -g plugman`
`npm install -g plugman@1.5`

then add your plugin specifying full path to

`plugman -d install --platform android --project 'platforms/android' --plugin '/Users/blah/my-cordova-plugin'`